# sql make geometric sequence from series of bit values

Tags: sql, sequence

I have this table:

```
declare @Table table (value int)
insert @Table select 0
insert @Table select 1
insert @Table select 1
insert @Table select 1
insert @Table select 0
insert @Table select 1
insert @Table select 1
```

Now, I need to make a Select query, which would add a column. This column will make a geometric sequence once there is a serie of value 1 in column value.

This would be the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would phrase this as an arithmetic problem.  First, you problem suggests that the ordering of rows is important.  Hence, you need a column to specify the ordering.  I assume there is an `id` column with this information.

Then to create the groups where the sequences start, do a cumulative sum of the `0`s -- all the `1` are in the same group.  Given the data you can express this as `sum(1 - value) over (order by id)`.

Then just use arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       value * power(2, row_number() over (partition by grp order by id) - 1) as generatedsequence
from (select t.*, sum(1 - value) over (order by id) as grp
      from @table t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf5abd38a46b11eb51b53f73ca84b1fc) is a db<>fiddle.

The arithmetic is that you want to enumerate the values in the group and then raise 2 to that power (except when `value` is `0`).  So the subquery returns:

```
id.    value    grp
1         1      1
2         1      1
3         1      1
4         1      1
5         0      2
6         1      2
7         1      2
```

The `row_number()` then enumerates the values within each `grp`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank You, Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

OK.. first things first, in a database there is no inherent ordering of the data within a table. Therefore, to do what you want, you will need to make a field to sort/order on. In this case, I'm using an IDENTITY field called 'SortID'.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (SortID int IDENTITY(1,1), BitValue bit);
INSERT INTO #Table (BitValue)
VALUES (0), (1), (1), (1), (0), (1), (1);
```

This gives a table with the following starting data

```
SortID  BitValue
1       0
2       1
3       1
4       1
5       0
6       1
7       1
```

Now, to solve the problem

- One way to do it is via a recursive CTE - where the value of the current row is based on the values of the previous rows.
- However, recursive CTEs can have performance issues (they're loops, basically) so it's better to do a set-based approach if possible.
- In this case, as you want a geometric sequence which is 2 to the power of the relevant row number, we don't need the previous rows to calculate this row - we only need to know the row number

The following approach

- Uses a CTE to make a new field called 'GroupNum' which is used to group the rows together. Every time a row has a BitValue of 0, it increments the GroupNum by 1.

  - In your example, the first four rows would have `GroupNum = 1`, the remaining three would have `GroupNum = 2`
- Follows the above with a window function - partitioning by those group numbers, and getting the row_number (minus one) within each group.
- The final result is set as the power of a variable `@a` to the relevant row_number.

To match your example, I have used `@a = 2` as the base for the POWER function.

```
DECLARE @a int;
SET @a = 2;

WITH Grouped_BitValues AS
    (SELECT SortID, BitValue, 
            CASE WHEN BitValue = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NewGrpFlag,
            SUM(CASE WHEN BitValue = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY SortID) AS GroupNum            
    FROM    #Table
    )
SELECT  BitValue, POWER(@a, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupNum ORDER BY SortID) -1) AS Geometric_Sequence
FROM Grouped_BitValues
ORDER BY SortID;
```

And here are the results

```
BitValue  Geometric_Sequence
0         1
1         2
1         4
1         8
0         1
1         2
1         4
```

Note that in your question, 2^0 should be 1, not 0, for a proper geometric sequence. If instead you wanted 0, you'd need to code in Geometric_Sequence to have a CASE expression (e.g., `CASE WHEN BitValue = 0 THEN 0 ELSE POWER(...) AS Geometric_Sequence`).

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=878866a27d8676456637c22923dded64) with

- the setup
- the answer
- the components of the answer (e.g., the CTE, and calculations) to demonstrate how it's calculated

Comment: not a bad solution. It works in fact, but I supposed Gordon's solution is faster, more readable, simplier. Anyway, thanks.